# REST API Query Syntax

Tags: 2013, rest, syntax, api

I'm trying to pull back all Projects that are Active and have a `ProjectName="X"`. `ProjectName` is a **lookup** and `Active` is **Yes/No**. Here's what I have built:

```
http://<siteurl>/_api/lists/getbytitle('Project%20Locations')/items?$select=Title,ProjectName
```

I'm getting the error:

> The query to field `ProjectName` is not valid. The `$select` query
>   string must specify the target fields and the `$expand` query string
>   must contains `ProjectName`

What's wrong with my syntax and how can I build a clause in for `ProjectName="X"` and `Active="Yes"` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try following. I am assuming that you have included `Title` column in your lookup column.

Building a clause for `ProjectName="X"` and `Active="Yes"`, you have to use `$filter` operator.

```
http://<siteurl>/_api/lists/getbytitle('Project%20Locations')/items?$select=Title,ProjectName/Title&$expand=ProjectName&$filter=Active eq 1 and ProjectName/Title eq 'X'
```

**Meaning of the error.**

> You have to `$expand` your lookup columns. Target column must be specified in the `$select`

**Regarding `$filter` by lookup column**

1. You need to `$expand` that column
2. In `$select`, you have to specify which columns you need to retrieve from lookup column. For example, your lookup list has several columns like `Title`, `Name`, `EstimatedDate`, `CloseDate` and others. Now you need `Title` and `Name`. So your query string is `$select=ProjectName/Title,ProjectName/Name&$expand=ProjectName`
3. Now you can `$filter` where `ProjectName/Title="X"` or `ProjectName/Name="Y"`. Remember you can not $filter something directly like `ProjectName="X"`. So your $filter should look like `$filter=Active eq true and ProjectName/Title eq 'X'`

Let me know for more explanation *OR* have a look on my article

[CRUD Operation to List Using SharePoint 2013 Rest API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API)

Comment: Great answer! All I had to change was Active = 1 instead of true and it returned the results needed

Comment: Yeah ... you are right! It should be `Active eq 1`